# Big feline camouflage in savannah/grassland?

Tags: science-based, biology, fauna

I'm working on a big feline who lives in savannas and grasslands. It's a solitary ambush predator, 1,4m / 4' 7'' to the shoulder, preys upon medium and big animals (antelopes, buffaloes, camelids, ground sloths), not very fast but powerful. My question is, what's the best camouflage for an animal like this? or it doesn't matter? I mean, we have tigers with stripes, cheetahs and leopards with spots, lions and pumas plain yellow/brown, African wild dogs with yellow, red and black spots, etc. What kind of fur would be better for this really big cat?

A more detailed image of the savanna/grassland: climate like Africa, very few trees, reddish-brown stones, shrubs and grasses between 30cm-1,2m / 1-4foot tall.

Comment: What time of day do they like to hunt?

Comment: @EveninginGethsemane they preffer to hunt during the day.

Comment: You seem to be aware that there are felines taht more or less match your description. 
Maybe you should let us know why you are not using them?

Comment: This description perfectly matches the smilodon or sabretooth

Comment: You're received some well-received answers - but all they've done is explain how your feline *could* be camouflaged. Camo only makes sense when being hunted. Does your feline have predators? If not, no camo is needed. If so, we need to know more about those predators so we can give you more specific answers.

Comment: "Camo only makes sense when being hunted."? Camo lets the predator get close enough to pounce.

Comment: "solitary ambush predator" - then it will likely have stripes or spots. ...  *'hunts in a pack whatever it wants whenever it wants'*, then it can be solid colors like lionesses.

Comment: @Mazura Keep in mind that most male lions have solid coloring and live alone; so, pack hunting is not a factor for lions.  Lions are mostly nocturnal hunters.  So, while they do rely on stealth, they do not need camo to be stealthy.  In contrast, the cheetah hunts at daytime; so, it needs its camo.

Comment: @Mazura but pumas and jaguarundis are lonely hunters and have plain colors. Without forgetting that they hunt in a wide variety of terrains (jungles, forests, mountains and grasslands)

Comment: The most successful hunter on the planet is the black footed cat, which looks just like my tabby with stripes. It never hurts to have camo but *does it matter*? Not really, considering pumas and the like. The feline is the pinnacle of mammalian body structures. It could be bioluminescent neon orange; still gonna win. Camo is just gravy.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Multi-Scale Camouflage

According to decades of military research, [multi-scale camouflage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-scale_camouflage) is the most effective pattern you can use for passive camouflage, and has become the basis for most passive camouflage patterns used today.  The idea behind multi-scale camouflage is that your pattern has large chunks of colors, but those large chunks are super imposed with smaller patterns as well.  This style of patterning is effective for 2 reasons.

1. In nature, objects tend to have multiple scales like this.  IE: a pattern of rocks contains smaller patterns of bumps and shadows or a pattern of branches contains smaller patterns of leaves, so on and so forth. So, multi-scale camouflage most accurately represents a typical environment you would need to blend into.
2. When you use camo that has too small of a pattern, it loses contrast at a distance and all the colors blend together so that it fails to disrupt your outline. When your pattern is too big, it fails to disrupt your outline at closer ranges because the pattern blocks become large flat visual objects themselves.  Multi-scale camouflage works at both near and far ranges unlike any single-scale pattern can.

So for Savana, you want a pattern that looks sort of like this:

[image]

One thing to note though is that the "digital" patterns used in military camo are not necessarily the best shape, it's just easier to design and manufacture.  In nature, multi-scale camouflage can be made up of more amorphous shapes.

[image]

Of the existing Savana large game predators, the best camo probably belongs to the [African wild dog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_wild_dog)  because its fur pattern includes these sorts of large color blocks disrupted by smaller patterns. Their exact patterning is more ideal for the arid forests around the edges of the Savana than the open grassy parts, but by minimizing the the deep blacks, and focusing more on yellow, orange, tan, and umber using the same general patterning, you should have an ideal tall grass ambush hunter.

[image]

Answer (score 30):

The best camouflage depends on the visual skills of the target preys of this feline.

It's well known that the [tiger stripes](https://www.iflscience.com/plants-and-animals/we-now-know-why-tigers-bright-orange-color-is-actually-excellent-camouflage/), for example, are effective at hiding it from the view of dichromats (a), while for trichromats (b) they are pretty flashy

[image]

As another example, to somebody using IR visors or echolocation, a person wearing a mimetic suit is as visible as if they were naked.

Therefore you should first decide which type of vision the preys of this feline have, and then design its camouflage based on that.

Comment: I fully agree that the coloring matters based on the optical range of the prey, but this question seems to only 1/2 answer the question.  Spots, stripes, patches, flat, etc. may all have specific strengths and weaknesses regardless of the color range of of the prey animals eyes.